# Unable to launch the application from notification in Xamarin android after Android 13 release

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am facing an issue after Android OS 13 release. On taping on the notification I am not able to launch the application. I'm using Pending intent in the notification, below is the code and error I a m getting in logs

```
private static PendingIntent GetAnswerCallIntent(Context context)
        {
            var intent = new Intent(CallIntents.Answer);
            //intent.SetAction(Long.ToString(1));
            intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.BroughtToFront);
            intent.SetClass(context, typeof(MainActivity));
            intent.PutExtra(nameof(CallIntents), CallIntents.Answer);
            return PendingIntent.GetActivity(context, (int)ActivityRequestCode.IncomingCallAnswerIntent, intent, PendingIntentFlags.Immutable);
        }

[ANR_LOG] >>> msg's executing time is too long
[ANR_LOG] Blocked msg = { when=-4s376ms what=113 target=android.app.ActivityThread$H obj=ReceiverData{intent=Intent { act=com.landmarkhealth.patient.INCOMING_CALL_ANSWER flg=0x30080010 cmp=org.landmarkhealth.patient/LandmarkHealth.Patient.Droid.Connectivity.IncomingCallBroadcastReceiver (has extras) } packageName=org.landmarkhealth.patient resultCode=0 resultData=null resultExtras=null} } , cost  = 4376 ms
[ANR_LOG] >>>Current msg List is:
[ANR_LOG] >>>CURRENT MSG DUMP OVER<<<
```

Comment: Did you try to debug it to reproduce the problem and find which line cause the problem?